# Bad request error when reading a web page

Tags: java

I was trying to read a web page in bytes but it always returns "Bad Request Error 400" message on my java console ( I'm displaying the content on my console). I couldn't find the way to correct it maybe it is because of my reading bytes code.Here is my code and result:

```
Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(req.hostname), 80);
                    PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                    socketOut.print("GET "+ req.url + "\n\n");
                    socketOut.flush();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int data = in.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                      char theChar = (char) data;
                      buffer.append(theChar);
                      data = in.read();
                    }
                    in.close();
                    byte[] result = buffer.toString().getBytes();
                    out.write(result);
```

And the result contains html tags starts from Bad request message but I delete them  so here is my result:

```
Thread with id 10 URL: http://www.facebook.com.tr/
Host: www.facebook.com.tr
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2012 10:18:06 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 134

400 Bad Request
Method Not Implemented
Invalid method in request
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it's because your code can't handle the permanent redirect it receives in the initial handshake:

```
$>> curl --head www.facebook.com.tr/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.facebook.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Debug: WOU3E4EGqo5Rxch8AnUzqcWg9CcM1p55pt1P9Wrm0QI=
Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2012 10:33:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Also check your question, it's a 400 you received not a 404.

Try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.facebook.com.tr").openStream()));

String line = reader.readLine();
while(line!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: A web address isn't simply a text file, you're attempting to communicate with a web server and need to perform certain handshakes to get the information you want. I'll update my answer with some code that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 400  is sent HTTP service when you have sent the incorrect or inappropriate request to a HTTP server. You have to be sure that whether your request is right. I see `www.facebook.com.tr`. Check on that `.tr`.

Answer (score 0):

The server is not tolerating an HTTP request with no [`HTTP-Version`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) declaration. Try it like this:

```
socketOut.print("GET "+ req.url + " HTTP/1.1\n\n");
```

Also take into account that the server is keeping the connection alive, so at some point the `data = in.read()` will lock the main thread. Unless you kill the connection or do something else, your loop will take a while to end until the connection times out.